# VIM - Use values of the editorconfig

Tags: vim, editorconfig

I want to include a mapping in my `.vimrc` file running tests automatically. Due to the variety of programming languages out there with thousands of testing frameworks, I want vim to fetch a specific value out of my [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file.

My current approach is this:

```sh
nnoremap <leader>t :w<CR>:!npm run test<CR>
```

The command `!npm run test<CR>` shall be swapped with a value out of the `.editorconfig` file

But this makes only one language possible.

Comment: You probably want an editorconfig plugin to do this

Comment: Do you know a plugin allowing me to use those variables?

Comment: Literally, [`editorconfig`](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[editorconfig/editorconfig-vim](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim) is performing well.

Thank you very much!